# Record two channels at the same time on Android MediaRecorder or using AudioRecord?

Tags: android, audiorecord, android-mediarecorder, android-audiorecord, channel

Can I record more than one channel at the same time either using MediaRecorder or AudioRecord? What I want is to be able to record both MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_UPLINK and VOICE_DOWNLINK at the same time. Can be into two separate files or to same file with two channels. I tried using two separate instances of MediaRecorder. But only the first one records. The second one says the input is unavailable. I also tried to use one MediaRecorder and one AudioRecord at the same time. Again, Both works individually but when AudioRecord comes after MediaRecorder is started, The following errors are shown.

```
05-21 03:40:42.735: E/AudioRecord(1322): Could not get audio input for record source 1
05-21 03:40:42.735: E/AudioRecord-JNI(1322): Error creating AudioRecord instance:     initialization check failed.
05-21 03:40:42.825: E/AudioRecord-Java(1322): [ android.media.AudioRecord ] Error code -20     when initializing native AudioRecord object.
```

I also tried to put the second MediaRecorder on a new thread. Again the same result. So this makes me wonder if it is possible to record simultaneously at all.  I was also thinking if i can use one AudioRecord with two channels set two separate inputs from VOICE_UPLINK and VOICE_DOWNLINK but I don't know how to set the sources if it is possible at all.

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

Lucifer's answer means AudioRecord cannot be called asynchronously having more than one instance running at the same time. Does anyone know a way in which AudioSource.VOICE_UPLINK and AudioSource.VOICE_DOWNLINK can be recorded at the same time? Maybe using a single instance of AudioRecord with multiple channels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my Knowledge, AudioRecording is a Synchronized Method. So you can not use do two recording at a same time.

When your code is going for Second Recording Process it is showing the error `05-21 03:40:42.735: E/AudioRecord(1322): Could not get audio input for record source 1` which purely means that Recording Channel is already busy by First one.

However this can possible by parallel processing of two thread in such a ways that first thread record for the a specific amount of time. when control passes two second thread, first thread stops recording and second one start recording and vice versa. But as per mobile device this will become more complex. So better you record one channel at a time.

You can create a queue of recording, which will do recording one by one.

Comment: Thanks. But I want to record a phone conversation. So I need to record both channels at the same time and cannot queue them. Is it possible to record both channels using a single instance of AudioRecord? I see option channelConfig can be  CHANNEL_IN_STEREO but can I set AudioSource.VOICE_UPLINK to Left and AudioSource.VOICE_DOWNLINK right for example?

Comment: well you can normally save the conversion, why do you need two channels for it ? Most of the android device has such in-built facility, just on it and get the recorded file directly

Comment: Actually, most of the android phones  disable the MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL option so that phone conversations cannot be recorded. It's the same case on my SE xperia but the VOICE_UPLINK and VOICE_DOWNLINK are recording separately. I suspect it is the same case for all android phones but I think this is the only option to record a conversation in my case.

Comment: @noxiouswinter how did u record both side conversation ? i am facing same problem.i can record voice call in samsung for both side using VOICE_CALL but can's record in sony Experia?

Comment: The purpose of the `VOICE_CALL` audio source is precisely to record both the uplink and downlink. I don't know about other companies, but I can say for a fact that it wasn't disabled intentionally at Sony (except maybe if it was deemed so buggy that it was better not to support it at all, but I don't recall any such instance) because I spent a few years as a developer in their audio team. Voice call recording support from the platform vendors was often buggy and/or incomplete. In some cases we fixed it ourself, but there were other times when we didn't because there was no time for it.